# Plotting distributions of all columns in an R data frame

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to come up with a clean way to plot a grid view of all the columns in an R data frame. The problem is my dataframe has both discrete and numeric values in it. For simplicity's sake, we can use the sample dataset provided by R called `iris`. I would use `par(mfrow(x, y))` to split my plots and maybe an `mapply` to cycle through each column? I'm unsure what's best here.

I'm thinking something akin to:

```
ggplot(iris, aes(Sepal.Length))+geom_density()
```

But instead plotted for each column. My concern is the "Species" column being discrete. Maybe "geom_density" wouldn't be the right plot to use here, but the idea is to see each of the data frame's variables distributions in one plot-- even the discrete ones. Bar plots for the discrete values would serve the purpose. Basically I'm trying to do the following:

- Cycle through each column in the data frame
- If numeric, plot a histogram
- If discrete (a string basically), plot a bar plot

Any thoughts or advice would be appreciated!

Comment: I'd strongly recommend `skimr` package to get an idea of distributions. Try this: `library(skimr);
skim(iris)`.

Comment: Something like `GGally::ggpairs(iris)`? Or you just want the univariates?

Comment: Using ggplot I tend to use one set of plots for numeric and another set for non numeric variables. Try this `library(tidyverse); 

iris %>% select_if(is.numeric) %>% 
  gather() %>% 
  ggplot(aes(value))+ geom_density()+ facet_wrap(~key); 

iris %>% select_if(negate(is.numeric)) %>% 
  gather() %>% 
  ggplot(aes(value))+ geom_bar()+ facet_wrap(~key)`. I don't post this as an answer, because you asked for one plot. :-)

Comment: Sometime its worth having a look at `plot(iris)`!!

Comment: `plot(iris)` is helpful indeed and is great for investigating correlations between variables. It doesn't focuses on the distribution of each variable.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the function `plot_grid` from the `cowplot` package. This function takes a list of plots generated by `ggplot` and created a new plot, cobining them in a grid.

First, create a list of plots with `lapply`, using `geom_density` for numeric variables and `geom_bar` for everything else.

```
my_plots <- lapply(names(iris), function(var_x){
  p <- 
    ggplot(iris) +
    aes_string(var_x)

  if(is.numeric(iris[[var_x]])) {
    p <- p + geom_density()

  } else {
    p <- p + geom_bar()
  } 

})
```

Now we simply call `plot_grid`.

```
plot_grid(plotlist = my_plots)
```

Comment: This worked great! I did have to update my version of R to get `cowplot` working but this is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks for introducing me to`is_numeric` and `cowplot`.